# MsalAuthProvider is returning ID Token and Access Token that is the same

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, bearer-token, msal.js

I am familiarizing myself with react-aad-msal library. I'm trying to use it for authentication and securing our APIs in Azure. I have a SPA, a "gateway" api, and three specific apis. The plan is to use implicit flow between the SPA and the gateway API. Between the gateway and the specific APIs, I plan to use client credentials flow. With the code below, I successfully obtain an id token and what is labeled as an access token. I use jwt-decode to decode the both tokens and they are the same. Is this the expected behavior of this provider? Or is there a config I can set to actually return an actual access token that I can pass along to the gateway API for validation?

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <AzureAD provider={authProvider} forceLogin={true}>
    <App />
  </AzureAD>,
  document.getElementById('root') 
  );
```